# LUA - Simple code supposed to work isn't working (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

Simple piece of code, supposed to work isn't working... I really can't understand this.
This is code:

```
local asd = 1
if not asd == nil then
print("works")
end
```

That's it, is not printing "works", ;-; sorry if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence fooled you:

```
if not asd == nil then
```

is equivalent to

```
if (not asd) == nil then
```

Try

```
if not (asd == nil) then
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, answer was doing

```
local asd = 1
if asd ~= nil then
print("works")
end
```

I didn't even knew that ~= is a thing wow

Comment: You don't even need to go that far. You can do `if asd then print("works") end`, because `asd` would be `nil` otherwise. Any value assigned to `asd` automatically makes it non-nil.

Comment: @Josh, I love how simple that is, but it also never hurts to be explicit. While `if asd then` works in this scenario, it is notably unreliable if `asd` is ever defined as a boolean.